# Passing parameters to symfony 5.4 form test not working

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit, php-8

I have tried for 5 hours already with no success... I have a Symfony 5.3 app and implemented a search page that's not tied to an entity. Works perfectly, however when creating a general availability test the parameters are not passed to the controller. I have tried mocking with the $_POST array, passing an array to the third parameter of $client->request(), but the result always shows a GET method is executed and the parameter is not included into the request.

The form is like this:

```
<form class="form-search" action="{{ path('search_result') }}" method="post">
    <input name="searchwords" placeholder="{{ 'search.placeholder'|trans }}" type="text" class="input-large search-query">
    <button type="submit" class="btn search rounded"><i class="far fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

In my controller can access the parameter "searchwords" with the following:

```
$vars = Request::createFromGlobals();
$temp_searchwords = explode(' ', $vars->get('searchwords'));
```

Now I'm trying to pass parameters during my General Availability Test

```
$crawler = $client->request('POST', '/de/search/result', ["searchwords" => "test"]);
```

The result shows that a GET method is used and the parameters are not passed to the Controller. I have also tried mocking with the $_POST system variable:

```
$_POST = ["searchwords" => "test strings"]
```

the Request::createFromGlobals(); gives no parameters in my Controller, perhaps because a GET method is used instead of the 'POST' as requested in my $client->request() call.

Another try taken from the official Symfony 5.3 documentation also failed with the parameter not passed to my controller:

```
$buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('');
$form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form();
$form['searchwords'] = "test string";
// at this point the $form object contains the parameter "searchwords" and the value "test string"
$crawler = $client->submit($form);
```

Question: How would I pass a parameter to my controller and force a 'POST' request in my test? As said, the search is working fine in a real browser environment.

Comment: Why not using symfony Form component to make your form ? I think you will retrieve your parameters easily in that way.

Comment: A form component is tied to an Entity and I do not need neither want an entity that's not to be persisted in the database. I'm afraid it might also create a dead database table. I see two problems, one of them to be solved: When tampering with the $_POST[] array the line "Request::createFromGlobals();" doesn't pull the globals from the $_POST array. OR: The "$client->request('POST', '/de/search/result', ["searchwords" => "test"]);" should do a post as requested, right now it performs a GET query for some unknown reason :(

Comment: `A form component is tied to an Entity` not necessary, you can build a Form componant without entity

Comment: I spent some time playing around with controllers, Twig resources and the WebTest. In short, I have not been able to create a working test. The overhead of using Symfony's Forms mechanism for such a simple process is impractical. However, after a total of 7 hours, I have now figured it out: I called the post variables via get(). But it is necessary to get them from the request object. Then the test also works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should anyone ever find themselves in this situation:

I have called the post variable "searchword" via the following function.

```
$vars = Request::createFromGlobals();
$searchwords = explode(' ', $vars->get('searchwords'));
```

However, this only works in the browser, because the WebTest creates a request object without a diversion via global variables.

The real solution is to Autowire the request object in your controller function and use it for parameter retrieval:

```
public function searchResultAction($_locale, DuddeSearch $ds, Request $request)
{
    [...]
    $searchwords = explode(' ', $request->get('searchwords'));
}
```

This problem is a beginner's mistake on my part. Autowiring is explicitly and prominently mentioned in Symfony's "Best Practices". The only difficulty was that my solution worked perfectly in the browser.